# Error in running functions of C++ package at command line

Tags: c++

I am new to packages in C++ and I am using Visual Studio to build the package. I have done that successfully but I can't run the functions of that package at the command line.

Error is

```
'graphgen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am following the instructions from this link
https://snap.stanford.edu/snap/install.html
where it says

> After the code is compiled, as shown above, it can be executed. The graphgen application is used here as an example.
>
> To run the graphgen example, open a command line application and execute the following command:
>
> ```
> cd examples/graphgen
> ./graphgen -g:w -n:1000 -k:4 -p:0.1 -o:smallworld.txt
> ```
>
> The command generates a Watts-Strogatz small-world graph where each node is connected to k=4 closest nodes and with the rewiring probability of p=0.1.

What to do?

Comment: Do you see the file `graphgen` in your output directory?

Comment: no...how do I see that?

Comment: Pretty much the only thing you can do is ensure that no errors resulted when following the build instructions.

Comment: You need to first find where the built binary lands.